# How to parse a json array with the same structure but different names

Tags: java, android, json, gson

I want to parse a json file but it goes by something like this :

```
CDG: {
id: "32569",
airport_name: "Charles De Gaulle",
latitude: "49.0167",
longitude: "2.55",
timezone: "2",
dst_indicator: "E",
city: "Paris",
country: "France",
country_code: "FR",
region: "TC1",
listing_display: "true",
pseudonyms: ""
},
ORY: {
id: "33539",
airport_name: "Orly",
latitude: "48.7167",
longitude: "2.3833",
timezone: "2",
dst_indicator: "E",
city: "Paris",
country: "France",
country_code: "FR",
region: "TC1",
listing_display: "true",
pseudonyms: ""
},
LBG: {
id: "123425",
airport_name: "Le Bourget",
latitude: "48.969444",
longitude: "2.441389",
timezone: "1",
dst_indicator: "E",
city: "Paris",
country: "France",
country_code: "FR",
region: "TC1",
listing_display: "true",
pseudonyms: ""
},
```

But there is about three thousands object like this. I've been always using Gson to parse my json objects, but how can i parse this kind of file ? And how can i retrieve the name "CDG" or "ORY" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
  String str = "{CDG: {\n"
                + "id: \"32569\",\n"
                + "airport_name: \"Charles De Gaulle\",\n"
                + "latitude: \"49.0167\",\n"
                + "longitude: \"2.55\",\n"
                + "timezone: \"2\",\n"
                + "dst_indicator: \"E\",\n"
                + "city: \"Paris\",\n"
                + "country: \"France\",\n"
                + "country_code: \"FR\",\n"
                + "region: \"TC1\",\n"
                + "listing_display: \"true\",\n"
                + "pseudonyms: \"\"\n"
                + "},\n"
                + "ORY: {\n"
                + "id: \"33539\",\n"
                + "airport_name: \"Orly\",\n"
                + "latitude: \"48.7167\",\n"
                + "longitude: \"2.3833\",\n"
                + "timezone: \"2\",\n"
                + "dst_indicator: \"E\",\n"
                + "city: \"Paris\",\n"
                + "country: \"France\",\n"
                + "country_code: \"FR\",\n"
                + "region: \"TC1\",\n"
                + "listing_display: \"true\",\n"
                + "pseudonyms: \"\"\n"
                + "},\n"
                + "LBG: {\n"
                + "id: \"123425\",\n"
                + "airport_name: \"Le Bourget\",\n"
                + "latitude: \"48.969444\",\n"
                + "longitude: \"2.441389\",\n"
                + "timezone: \"1\",\n"
                + "dst_indicator: \"E\",\n"
                + "city: \"Paris\",\n"
                + "country: \"France\",\n"
                + "country_code: \"FR\",\n"
                + "region: \"TC1\",\n"
                + "listing_display: \"true\",\n"
                + "pseudonyms: \"\"\n"
                + "}}";
```

Using gson, you can retrieve the key names as follows:

```
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        Object o = gson.fromJson(str, Object.class);
        List keys = new ArrayList();
        Collection values = null;
        if (o instanceof Map) {
            Map map = (Map) o;
            keys.addAll(map.keySet()); // collect keys at current level in hierarchy
            values = map.values();
        } else if (o instanceof Collection) {
            values = (Collection) o;
        }
        System.out.println(keys);// [CDG, ORY, LBG]
        for (int i = 0; i < keys.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(keys.get(i));
        }
```

and using [java-json](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjavajsonjar.htm) you can do as follows:

```
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(str);
        String[] names = jsonObject.getNames(jsonObject);
        for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {

            System.out.println(names[i]);// all names are printed here : LBG,ORY, etc

            // then parsing the names accordingly..
            JSONObject jsonObject1 = jsonObject.getJSONObject(names[i]);
            System.out.println(jsonObject1.getString("city"));
        }
```

For fetching json from url:

```
   public static String connectionGet(String url, String parameter) throws MalformedURLException, ProtocolException, IOException {

    URL url1 = new URL(url);
    HttpURLConnection request1 = (HttpURLConnection) url1.openConnection();
    request1.setRequestMethod("GET");
    request1.connect();
    String responseBody = convertStreamToString(request1.getInputStream());
    return responseBody;
}

String str = connectionGet("http://www.cleartrip.com/common/json/airports.json", "");
```

Comment: He want this to be done using Gson!

Comment: Using GSON then in that case objects have to be defined for them. one for the first, and the other for the second having the same properties, and talking about 3000 such objects :O.. you could look into gson tutorial site :).

Comment: I'm still going to try this way.

Comment: @LalitPoptani have edited the answer , now the names can be retrieved using gson.

Comment: @Tsunaze have edited the answer, you can do it using gson also

Comment: I had an error : "com.google.gson.JsonParseException: Type information is unavailable, and the target object is not a primitive:"

Comment: @Tsunaze which line from the above code gave that error?

Comment: It doesn't give me any line but i think it's this one : Object o = gson.fromJson(str, Object.class); It tries to parse but doesn't comprehend it. Do i need to remove the "Object.class" and put my Class instead ?

Comment: no, thats not needed , did you copy 'str' from the above code?? or you wrote that from your question, because in your question the json format is not enclosed properly.

Comment: not, it's from my json, it's located here : http://www.cleartrip.com/common/json/airports.json

Comment: @Tsunaze have fetched the json from url and passed the str from there as shown in my edit, have tried and it works.

Comment: No what i did is take the json in the assets and read it from it because it's for data consumption

Comment: I have tried putting the json from the link u described, it works, to find the problem , you can try putting the json in the example statically and check if its working or not, so that you can know if the problem is in json format or the code.

Comment: No it's ok now, i'm going to use the second method, but getNames doesn't exist, so i tweaked it, and it now works.

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrayList<String> keylist = new ArrayList<String>();

            for ( String key : your_map_name.keySet() ) {
                System.out.println( key );
                keylist.add(""+key);
            }
```

so from this you can get all the key of map without any tnsn and just add it into the arraylist so after just pass key as a arraylist index value and get the value of map so u not worry about the json key whatever it is it will be store in the arraylist index. :)