# How to parse unknown JSON structure in Java

Tags: java, android, json

I have this bit of code:

```
JSONArray data = object.getJSONArray("Test");

for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++)
{
    JSONObject dataObject = data.getJSONObject(i);
    etc ...
```

I don't know before run time what I will have in dataObject though. Is it possible to loop through the keys somehow?

I thought this might work, as I saw it mentioned in another Stackoverflow article:

```
for (String key : dataObject.keys())
```

But I get an error saying "Can only iterate over an array or an instance of java.lang.Iterable"

Does anyone know how it can be done?

Comment: Can you post your Json structure?

Comment: post your JSON structure

Comment: It will be determined dynamically, but it will look something like this: {"Test":[{"CouldBeAnything":"CBA_Value","CouldBeSomethingElse":"CBSE_Value", ... }, {"CouldBeAnything2":"CBA2_Value","CouldBeSomethingElse2":"CBSE2_Value", ... }]}

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19398204/how-to-parse-a-json-array-with-the-same-structure-but-different-names/19398566#19398566)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To Retrieving the keys of your object this might work :

```
Iterator<?> iterator = object.keys();
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
   String key = (String)iterator.next();
   //do what you want with the key.                 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
JSONArray names()
Returns an array containing the string names in this object.
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help

```
Object obj = parser.parse(s);
JSONArray array = (JSONArray)obj;
```

Refer below link

http://json.org/java/

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/json/json_java_example.htm

Answer (score 0):

i guess

> Iterator  keys = json.keys();

this will give you the keys of your json object as java iterator

[How can I iterate JSONObject to get individual items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12870332/how-can-i-iterate-jsonobject-to-get-individual-items)

This will give you an idea to get the keys and values in iterative manner and helps you to implement for your need